# When deploying a web application I get the exception NoClassDefFoundError:LocalizableImpl

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat

I have a standard J2EE web application that includes web services. I'm using the `webservices-rt` library to host the services. [See the maven dependency below]. However, I get the following exception at run time:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/ws/util/localization/LocalizableImpl
    at com.sun.xml.ws.util.exception.JAXWSExceptionBase.<init>(JAXWSExceptionBase.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException.<init>(WSServletException.java:47)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [...]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.util.localization.LocalizableImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 33 more
```

**Maven WS Dependency**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Am I missing a library? I've tried adding `jaxws-rt`. However, that requires an additional repo [`jboss`]. I'm a bit leery of that, as that it introduces a lot of new libraries into the project.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Maven, add below to your project should solve your problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You don't have to add others jar because it will automatically pull the rest of dependencies. I prefer to add the jar to my war instead of Tomcat lib. I think it is more portable.

Answer (score 1):

try

The JAX-WS dependency library “jaxws-rt.jar” is missing.

Go here http://jax-ws.java.net/.

Download JAX-WS RI distribution.

Unzip it and copy “jaxws-rt.jar” to Tomcat library folder “{$TOMCAT}/lib“.

Restart Tomcat.

Comment: Copy-pasta http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-ws-transport-http-servlet-wsservletcontextlistener/ ?

Answer (score 1):

For a maven, tomcat application try these dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- jax-ws maven dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- servlet provided by tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.stream.buffer/streambuffer -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream.buffer</groupId>
        <artifactId>streambuffer</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/policy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>policy</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.gmbal/gmbal-api-only -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.gmbal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmbal-api-only</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0-b003</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.ha/ha-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.ha</groupId>
        <artifactId>ha-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I hope this works for new people who will face this issue

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the JBoss repo doesn't automatically import the repo libraries. It simply makes the libraries available for importing.

Bottom line is that if you want to use a class that's in a library, then you have to pull the library into your project. If the library is in the JBoss repo, then you have to declare the JBoss repo.

Comment: I understand, but it also brings in libraries that may be used by the JBoss platform. I wish to bring in the minimum external libraries needed to perform the task.

Comment: I'm responding to the part where you say you're leery of declaring the JBoss repo because you're concerned that it may pull in extra dependencies. That should not be a worry since declaring a repo doesn't pull in dependencies. If a particular dependency is pulling in other dependencies you don't want, you can use dependency exclusions.